# JavaScript - Save selected option from multiple select lists with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to save all selected options in an array for later output. I found already many suggestions but it is still not working for me. class-names and name can't be changed.

**HTML**

```
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-farbe-0">
<option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="rot-1">Rot</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="gelb-2">Gelb</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="schwarz-3">Schwarz</option>
</select>

<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-groesse-1">
<option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="100-1">100</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="200-2">200</option>
<option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="300-3">300</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.addon-select').change(function () {
    var result = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result;
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: When do you want to display the selected values, on a click of a button or something?

Comment: Actually i don't want to display them at all, i need them to send per mail later. i just have the output code for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Snippet demonstrates the use of `.push()` array method, details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Create an empty array to store results
  var selected = [];

  // Delegate the change event on each .addon-select
  $('.addon-select').on('change', function() {

    // Store this .addon-select's value
    var result = $(this).val();

    // .push() the value into the selected array
    selected.push(result);

    $('#test').append('<li>' + result + '</li>');

    // Display the selected array on console
    console.log(selected);

  });

});
```

```css
select {
  width: 16ch;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-farbe-0">
  <option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="rot-1">Rot</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="gelb-2">Gelb</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="schwarz-3">Schwarz</option>
</select>

<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-groesse-1">
  <option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="100-1">100</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="200-2">200</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="300-3">300</option>
</select>

<br>
<ol id="test" start='0'></ol>
```

Comment: halleluja it is working ... i just troubled with the output in the example of Nenad Vracar

Comment: One last question. Why this Output isn't working?

    $('#test').html(result.join('<br>'));

When i have 

    <div id="test"></div>

Comment: ?...Er I think you got mixed up @kratze, I'm zer00ne not Nenad Vracar. My `output`s work AFAIK.

Comment: Yes i know, i didn't mix it up. Your example works but i just tried to change the output. The point is, in this example i have just 2 select option forms but in my project there are sites with 5 forms and i need all selected values in an array also on the output they should be listed all at once just. Or with the array index.

Comment: @kratze I displayed it in one ordered list, if you don't want numbers you just change the `<ol>` to `<ul>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133752/discussion-between-kratze-and-zer00ne).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` and to return array of selected options.

```js
$('.addon').change(function() {
  var values = $('.addon').find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get()

  console.log(values)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-farbe-0">
  <option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="rot-1">Rot</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="gelb-2">Gelb</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="schwarz-3">Schwarz</option>
</select>

<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-9-groesse-1">
  <option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option...</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="100-1">100</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="200-2">200</option>
  <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="300-3">300</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will also work when i have more than 2 select boxes?
How can i output the stored values for testing?
I copied your code snipped and it's not showing the selected options in output yet.

Comment: You can check your console to see result, but you can also display it in html https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1458/

Comment: Yea thanks, but on my testpage it is not working yet. It must be jquery 2.1.1 ?

Comment: I am not sure what version are you using?

Comment: I tried both 2.1.1 and 3.1.1  
I have no clue what is wrong, the js fiddle works awesome but on my site i don't get any output.

Maybe it is useful to show my whole project? I am trying to include a button for a price suggestion option inside a wordpress woocommerce website. I added a custom function inside the wordpress theme and i am only coding inside this function.

Comment: Just try to `alert()` something to make sure you included your js files and jquery properly, also make sure you are using right selectors.